# Count the values after an underscore in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

| ID | event_1_positive | event_2_negative | event_3_neutral | event_4_negative | event_5_positive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

What I'd like to do is to order the events by its effect (positive, negative or neutral) and return the count for each effect.

In this case, my expected output would be:

```
0   negative   11
1   positive   9
2   neutral    5
```

Comment: Do you know when a negative column would occur and when positive would be there? or they can be random?

Comment: They would be random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter` and `groupby`:

```
>>> df.filter(like='event') \
      .groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[1], axis=1) \
      .sum().sum()

negative    11
neutral      5
positive     9
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create new columns where you add all the ones with similar effects, e.g.
`df["negative"] = df["event_2_negative"] + df["event_4_negative"]`
and then delete the other columns and then do a `df["negative"].value_counts()` for example or `df["negative"].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a rare case where accounting in a loop seems practical as there's a manageable count of columns

```py
# start a dictionary to pack with results
categories = {k: 0 for k in ("negative", "positive", "neutral")}

for colname in df:  # dataframes are iterable by-column name!
    if "_" not in colname:
        continue  # or consider alerting on this condition
    for category in categories.keys():
        if category in colname:  # substring compare
            categories[category] += df[colname].sum()
            break  # successfully found category -> next colname
    else:  # didn't find and break
        raise ValueError(f"no category for {colname}")

# create a collection of results
df_results = pd.Series(categories).to_frame().reset_index()
```

```
    index      0
0   negative   11
1   positive   9
2   neutral    5
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to reshape the data, where you have all the negatives in one column, same for positives and neutral. Your columns have a pattern (some end in positives, some columns end in neutral, ...).

We can use that pattern in [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer)  from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to reshape the data, then aggregate(reduce):

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df.pivot_longer(index='ID', 
                 names_to=('positive', 'negative', 'neutral'), 
                 names_pattern=('positive', 'negative', 'neutral'))
   .iloc[:, 1:]
   .sum()
) 
positive     9.0
negative    11.0
neutral      5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df. \
drop("ID", axis=1). \
rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("_")[2]). \
unstack(). \
droplevel(1). \
reset_index(). \
groupby("index"). \
sum()

#           0
# index     
# negative  11
# neutral   5
# positive  9
```